# Selenium Webdriver: find a span that has an inner span with specific text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, find

Using Selenimum Webdriver in Python, I want to be able to find `My Text` from the following html code:

```
<span class="first">My Text  
    <span class="second">(Total)</span>
</span>
```

The inner `span` has a unique word in it which is `(Total)`.
The outer `span` has the text that I am looking for, which is `My Text`. How can I find this text?

I have tried to use something like:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '(Total)')]/prededing-sibling::span")
```

But it was not successful.

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below solution to get required text:

```
span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[span="(Total)"]')
required_text =  driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[0].textContent', span).strip()
```

*Output of `print(required_text)`*

```
'My Text'
```

Note that `span` with text `"My Text"` is not a sibling of `span` with text `"(Total)"`, but its parent, so you can not fetch it with `preceding-sibling::span`

Comment: There are only two WebElement selenium can find, one is the parent `span`, other is the inner `span`,  you can't obtain an WebElement which only includes the `My Test`,  Because `My Test` is a TextNode (in HTML DOM Tree) which selenium won't return it as a WebElement.  If you want to get the `My Test` text content,  one way is use @Andersson solution, another is get the text  content of parent `span` then use split to get the first part of tect content, like <parent span>.text.split('(')[0]

Comment: @Andersoon. Thank you very much for the answer. It worked nicely. Can you please explain your solution so me and others understand it and then I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: @TJ1, In Selenium you cannot use XPath that returns you text nodes, so `//span[@class="first"]/text()` that intend to return required text will raise exception... Instead we use JavaScript code that allows to do the same: `childNodes[0]` returns you the first child node which is text node and `textContent` returns its value - `"My Text"`. `arguments[0]` its just a placeholder for a `span` variable. In the same way you can use `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("span.first").childNodes[0].textContent').strip()`

Answer (score -1):

You are using preceding sibling, that's wrong, you are looking at what's there in the parent node

So use this

```
"//span[text()='(Total)']/.."
```

The above xpath helps you to locate the corresponding parent node, and then you use programming language to get the particular string

I don't know Python, I would do in Ruby in the following way

```
a='(Total)'
puts b.element(xpath: "//span[text()='#{a}']/..").text.chomp(a).strip
=> My Text
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not returning the element I am looking for.

Comment: It's returning the span and from which I extracted the string My Text. Can you please let me know what's the element you are getting at? Can you please simply print the text using this xpath `"//span[text()='(Total)']/.."`